# How can I calculate the Squared Mahalanobis Distance for two columns in R studio?

Tags: r, statistics

If I have a text file which has 7 variables:

```
Wind Solar_Radiation CO NO NO2 O3 HC
  8      98           7  2  12  8  2
  7      107          4  3  9  5  3
  7      103          4  3  5  6  3
  10     88           5  2  8  15  4
  6      91           4  2  8  10  3
  8      90           5  2  12  12  4
  9      84           7  4  12  15  5
  5      72           6  4  21  14  4
  7      82           5  1  11  11  3
  8      64           5  2  13  9  4
```

But I just want to calculate the Squared Mahalanobis Distance for X5(NO2) and X6(O3), where Xj=(Xj5,Xj6)'. How can I do it? Thanks!

Can I do in this way:(airpolution is the file name)

```
x=data.frame(airpolution$NO2,airpolution$O3)
mean=colMeans(x)
s=cov(x)
D2=mahalanobis(x,mean,s)
```

Do I need to set inverted=True because the formula of Squared Mahalanobis Distance is S^-1?

Comment: Did you read https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/mahalanobis.html ?

Comment: Maybe `mahalanobis(x=df[,5:6],center = colMeans(df[,5:6]),cov = cov(df[,5:6]))`

Comment: @markus Yes. But I am not sure how to set the x.